# How to invoke InfiniBand with OpenMPI

Tags: cluster-computing, openmpi, hpc, infiniband

I would like to know how to invoke InfiniBand hardware on CentOS 6x cluster with OpenMPI (static libs.) for running my C++ code. This is how I compile and run:

/usr/local/open-mpi/1.10.7/bin/mpic++ -L/usr/local/open-mpi/1.10.7/lib -Bstatic main.cpp -o DoWork

usr/local/open-mpi/1.10.7/bin/mpiexec  -mca btl tcp,self --hostfile hostfile5 -host node01,node02,node03,node04,node05 -n 200 DoWork

Here, "**-mca btl tcp,self**" reveals that **TCP** is used, and the cluster has InfiniBand.

What should be changed in compiling and running commands for InfiniBand to be invoked? If I just replace "**-mca btl tcp,self**" with "**-mca btl openib,self**" then I get plenty of errors with relevant one saying:

*At least one pair of MPI processes are unable to reach each other for
MPI communications.  This means that no Open MPI device has indicated
that it can be used to communicate between these processes.  This is
an error; Open MPI requires that all MPI processes be able to reach
each other.  This error can sometimes be the result of forgetting to
specify the "self" BTL.*

Thanks very much!!!

Comment: Remove the `-mca btl ...` parameter. Open MPI is modular and it automatically picks up the best communication interface. If there is a usable InfiniBand hardware that Open MPI can detect, it will automatically use the `openib` module since it has much higher precedence than the TCP module.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply and help, Hristo. I have tried following: **usr/local/open-mpi/1.10.7/bin/mpiexec --hostfile hostfile5 -host node01,node02,node03,node04,node05 -n 200 DoWork** and it didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: What exactly didn't work?

Comment: Here is the error message:
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
No OpenFabrics connection schemes reported that they were able to be
used on a specific port.  As such, the openib BTL (OpenFabrics
support) will be disabled for this port.

  Local host:           node02
  Local device:         mlx5_1
  Local port:           1
  CPCs attempted:       rdmacm, udcm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: If I check InfiniBand settings with "ibhost" command, I get following errors:

-bash-4.1$ ibhosts
ibwarn: [168793] mad_rpc_open_port: client_register for mgmt 1 failed
src/ibnetdisc.cand:766; can't open MAD port ((null):0)
/usr/sbin/ibnetdiscover: iberror: failed: discover failed

Comment: The latter message means that the `ib_mad` (or was it `ib_umad`?) kernel module is not loaded, so the MAD interface is missing. It is an InfiniBand software configuration problem, so not really for Stack Overflow. Try on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Thanks Hristo. I'll see to talk to our "root" next week to ask if they can properly install ib.

Comment: Here is addtional info, I appreciate if you can comment. I did ibstat on the login node and among the large output, here are the important four lines:
mlx5_ 0: Physical state: LinkUp
mlx5_ 1: Physical state: LinkUp
mlx5_ 2: Physical state: Disabled
mlx5_ 3: Physical state: Disabled

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Does this definitely show that on this node the two out of four processors are not having InfiniBand connection? There are two sockets, and each socket holds two processors (each processor 10 cores, each core 2 logical threads). So, one socket (two processors) is not connected with InfiniBand.

Comment: No, it's a 4-port InfiniBand HCA with only two ports connected. It doesn't limit the CPUs that have access to it in any way.

Comment: I was told by the "root" that in this machine is RoCE (RDMA over Converged Ethernet)  with 100Gb/s.

Comment: I guess RoCE gets automatically used when I use mpiexec with " -mca btl tcp,self" params.

Comment: Consult the Open MPI FAQ on [running it over RoCE](http://www.open-mpi.de/faq/?category=openfabrics#ompi-over-roce). The crucial parameter is probably the one that enables the `rdmacm` CPC: `--mca btl_openib_cpc_include rdmacm`.